# Reorder list through span custom value javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

```
<ul id="CoreWebsiteTopHeader_6_list"><li><a class="navigation" href="/seller"><span class="editableLinks" data-id="32638" data-sort="110">Seller</span></a></li><li><a class="navigation" href="/about"><span class="editableLinks" data-id="32639" data-sort="10">About</span></a></li><li><a class="navigation" href="/faqs"><span class="editableLinks" data-id="32641" data-sort="40">FAQs</span></a></li><li><a class="navigation" href="/privatelending"><span class="editableLinks" data-id="32646" data-sort="60">Private Lending</span></a></li><li><a class="navigation" href="/problemproperty"><span class="editableLinks" data-id="32647" data-sort="70">Problem Property</span></a></li><li class="current"><a class="navigation" href="/quickoffer"><span class="editableLinks" data-id="32648" data-sort="90">Quick Offer</span></a></li><li><a class="navigation" href="/woahslowdown"><span class="editableLinks" data-id="32650" data-sort="120">Stop Foreclosure</span></a></li></ul>
```

This here is my unordered list that is created programatically. I am looking to use javascript to reorder this list by the data-sort value inside of each span tag. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Here is my attempt using javascript pretty sure i am just missing something

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li').sort(sortEm).prependTo($('ul#list'));
    // Handler for .ready() called.
});
function sortEm(a, b) {
    return parseInt($('span', a).getAttribute('data-sort')) < parseInt($('span', b).getAttribute('data-sort')) ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Comment: Where's your attempt? This is not hard to search for on the web. SO isn't a code writing factory

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
  
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('li').sort(sortEm).prependTo($('ul#list'));
        // Handler for .ready() called.
    });
    function sortEm(a, b) {
        return parseInt($('span', a).getAttribute('data-sort')) < parseInt($('span', b).getAttribute('data-sort')) ? 1 : -1;
    }
   
</script>

Comment: jQuery doesn't have a method `getAttribute()`. Look at errors your code throws.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
var li = $("li");

li.sort(compare);
function compare(a, b) {
    var a_data = $('span',a).data("sort"), b_data = $('span',b).data("sort");

    return (+a_data) - (+b_data);
}

$("#CoreWebsiteTopHeader_6_list").empty();
$.each(li, function() {
    $("#CoreWebsiteTopHeader_6_list").append(this);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uok41396/6/)

Comment: That would be perfect except sometimes the CoreWebsiteTopHeader_6 is a CoreWebsiteTopHeader_7 or a different number.

Comment: @Snake3ite expose the problem and I'll try to solve it, there's no problem in changing it to any other id (even dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

You are right there, just replace your `getAttribute(` with `attr(`  or use `data(` like @acontell mentioned.  And BTW your condition is reversed (set for descending order) not sure if that is intentional, if not swap the -1 and 1.

```
$(function () {
    $('li').sort(function(a, b){
        return $('span', a).data('sort') < $('span', b).data('sort') ? -1 : 1;
    }).prependTo($('ul'));
    // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```